# Question about the bootstrap of BFV

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

The description of bootstrapping in Section 5 of the BFV paper (https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/144) is somewhat challenging to grasp, and I have two specific questions:

1. The author mentions that if the norm of $\mathbf{v}$ is restricted such that $\|\mathbf{v}\|<\Delta / \mu$ for some $\mu>2$, it allows us to largely disregard most of $\operatorname{ct}[0]$ and $\operatorname{ct}[1]$. Subsequently, the author suggests replacing $\operatorname{ct}[0]$ and $\operatorname{ct}[1]$ with $\mathbf{c}_0=\operatorname{ct}[0]+\mathbf{e}_0$ and $\mathbf{c}_1=\operatorname{ct}[1]+\mathbf{e}_1$, where $\left\|\mathbf{e}_i\right\|<\Delta / \nu$. What is the intention behind adding $\mathbf{e}_0$ to $\mathbf{c}_0$ and $\mathbf{e}_1$ to $\mathbf{c}_1$ ? My hypothesis is that this addition serves to nullify the lower bits of $\mathbf{c}_0$ and $\mathbf{c}_1$, similar to the truncation process. Am I on the right track with this interpretation?
2. Given the noise of the expression $\mathbf{c}_0+\mathbf{c}_1 \cdot \mathbf{s}=\Delta \cdot \mathbf{m}+\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{e}_0+\mathbf{e}_1 \cdot \mathbf{s}+q \cdot \mathbf{r}$, which is quantified as $\Delta / \mu+(H(f) \cdot h+1) \cdot \Delta / \nu$, the author infers that we can utilize the upper segments of $\operatorname{ct}[0] \bmod q$ and $\operatorname{ct}[1] \bmod q$. These segments have a size defined as $S_R=\operatorname{size}(\lceil\nu \cdot t\rceil)$ bits. How is this determination derived?

Comment: In general when you use notation from a paper you should link to the particular paper you are reading, unless you are certain the notation is standard in the area. This is especially true as I don't believe there is a "BFV" paper, and instead there is a B paper (in the LWE setting) and an FV paper (in the RLWE setting).

Comment: It's worth mentioning as well that if you are interested in BFV there are more modern approaches to it that have better performance, e.g. [this](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/204.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the reminder. I've updated the question and included the link to the paper.